# root url javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm working on an .Net ASP MVC razor application

The root url on the server being "myWebSite.com/myApp/"

I need to find dynamically this url to have the right url to make some Ajax call to action like this

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: root + "/Controller/Action",
        data: ...
    }
```

I read a few things here and there but what I found doesn't work

```
"document.location.hostname" -> "myWebSite.com"
"location.host"              -> "myWebSite.com"
"window.location.pathname"   -> "/myApp/"
```

Last one sounded promissing but if I navigate in the website :

```
 for an url :  "myWebSite.com/myApp/Controller/Action?1" 
 "window.location.pathname"   -> "/myApp/Controller/Action"
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In asp.net mvc, using razor view engine, I got this in my layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var baseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";
</script>
```

That way we can define application base url as javascript object that is accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find this. Use realtive path:

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "Controller/Action",
        data: ...
    }
```

This will go in as `<root>/Controller/Action`

Comment: That's actually what i use locally but on the server I have to write
url: "MyApp/Controller/Action"
that's the only way it seems to work but it's a pain in the ass to have to change the link everytime I put it on the server 

and even if it worked, i need to display some icon on a googlemap, for that i need i also need the correct root

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var root = "<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>";
alert(root);
```

Does it give correct root URL?

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

In razor:

```
Uri auxBaseUri = new Uri(Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
Uri baseUri = new Uri(auxBaseUri, Url.Content("~"));
```

Then in the js I use:

```
var baseUrl = "@baseUri.ToString()";

$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "Controller/Action",
    ...
```

It works on my machine and on the server.
Hope it helps